# Is the ship to ship combat in the Star Trek movies meant to evoke the 'Age of Sail'?

Tags: star-trek

During the battle scene in Wrath of Khan both ships appear to make passes at each other and fire 'broadsides' in a manner very similar to that of ships of the line in the 19th century and any number of movies based on that period.

Moreover is it part of their training/experience that Kirk and Khan both think in terms of a two dimensional battle until Spock points out the possible weakness in Khan's thinking?

Star Wars in comparison seems designed to be an homage to the fighter combat of WWII and the likewise many movies based on that period.

So does the iconic battle in the Wrath of Khan evoke the '[Golden Age of Sail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Sail)' and set the tone for the other movies?

Comment: Sidenote: if you want to see an SF setting with space combat modelled after Age of Sail naval combat to an almost ridiculous degree (while taking great pains to make it plausible), take a look at David Weber's "Honor Harrington" books.

Comment: Note that in Star Trek Online, which I play a lot, the ships are heavily restricted in what movements they can make in order to closely match the feel of the movies. a fair number of people have tried to get the developers to change this but they have stuck to their decision very well and the game benefits from it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The battle in the Mutara nebula was meant to evoke submarine warfare; the film's director Nicholas Meyer mentions this specifically in the DVD commentary during the battle.  Besides the battle mechanics, the sweater tied around Merritt Butrick's neck as he enters the bridge was a subtle sight cue for the audience.

Rather than setting the tone, I think the *Wrath of Khan* battle was what we would expect from Star Trek given the admittedly few prior battle scenes from the original series.  The tactics were the same, large ships presenting minimal aspect as much as possible while trying to hit the enemy with heavy guns and torpedos.  The battle in the nebula was an aberration because the nebula's interference made ship's sensors inoperable.  Only then was it tactically sound to break plane with the enemy, exposing more of your ship to attack in exchange for the chance to catch the enemy unaware.

Comment: I always thought it was a kind of submarine version of Moby Dick, with Khan and Kirk both treating each other as the whale

Comment: @Kyle I'd like to hear what you have to say about the 'setting the tone' element of the question please

Comment: @User I've tried to address it in an edit.

Comment: @KyleJones Nice edit, I've marked it as the best answer

Comment: How was the sweater tied around Butrick's neck a cue? I'm not familiar with what that may be referencing.

Comment: @Thomas I believe Meyer was referring to the Royal Navy [roll-neck sweaters](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Royal-Navy-Rollneck-Sub-Sweater/dp/B003L6CJ1I), which apparently have a long history.

Comment: Another "clue" that is is a allegory for a submarine fight, on the enterprise bridge you could hear a audible "sonar ping" on the bridge during the nebula battle scene. I could not find a clip of it on youtube, if anyone could provide one...

Comment: The sweater around Merritt Butrick's neck always seemed to me to be more of a warning that preppies could survive for another 300 years.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. The first battle scene, when the two ships are approaching each other and Kirk makes the comment about it being "Damned peculiar", isn't really even a true combat- it's more an ambush. I would say this is what you're considering the "broadside" scene, and is purely a consequence of two things- that the Enterprise didn't realize that it was entering a combat, and that Khan didn't wish to destroy the Enterprise completely, or there likely would have been torpedoes involved.

The scene in the nebula, on the other hand, was more of a hunter and hunted battle. The two ships were exchanging fire as the opportunity permitted- nothing "Age of Sail" involved there. Torpedoes weren't able to be used accurately.

The combat in Star Trek has always struck me as pretty singular. It's a strange combination of rifle batteries (phasers) and missile batteries (torpedoes). It's not what one would consider very long range, and it's not clear at what speed it takes place- although warp speed seems to be out. I enjoy the combat scenes, but not for it's realism from a ship to ship point. Some of the internal scenes, with damage control efforts, etc, are very realistic.